# How to create checkbox on every new line in jquery+ jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to create checkbok on every new line .I got the event of new line by checking the height.But I need to add two div in main div in which first div contain checkbox .and second div contain data .I am facing in difficulties in that thing

here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/TnTj9/1/

```
$(function() {
  var h = -1;
  setInterval(function () {


    var newHeight = $('#realTimeContents').append("Hiiiii. is div").height();
    if(h == -1) h = newHeight;
    if(h != newHeight) {
        h = newHeight;
//        alert("I've changed height");
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

I need to use checkbox in left div like this but not able to do that.

```
$("#leftdiv").append( "<label for='chk_" + idCounter + "'>" + val + "</label><input id='chk_" + idCounter + "' type='checkbox' value='" + val + "' />" );
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why are you using an Interval

Comment: actually I am getting data from server after a regular interval of time

Comment: So it I take as regular interval of time

Comment: Do you mean like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnTj9/2/)?

Comment: Can you show us an image of the result you're trying to get?

Comment: @dc5, it appears he wants a checkbox everytime his content wraps to a new line.

Comment: @dc no..where is checkbox ?

Comment: Is the widgth of `#realTimeContents` static?

Comment: @itay I don't have .But it a simple checkbox = contend then new line again checkbox=contend.mean we have to take two div in which one have 30% width other have 70% with

Comment: @smerny #realTimeContents is main div in which i think we have to take  two div

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words - very true in this case :)

Comment: sorry I don't have actually i am implementing marker ..:(

Comment: Draw a sketch anything to get the idea across a bit better.  Is this closer: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnTj9/4/)?

Comment: exactly but contend its more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TnTj9/5/)

JS:

```
$(function() {
  var h = -1;
  setInterval(function () {
    var newHeight = $('#realTimeContents').append("Hiiiii. is div").height();
    if(h == -1) h = newHeight;
    if(h != newHeight) {
        h = newHeight;
        $("#left").append("<div class='cb'><input type=\"checkbox\" /></div>");
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float:left;
}
#realTimeContents {
    width:400px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.cb {
    height:25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left"><div class='cb'><input type="checkbox" /></div></div><div id="realTimeContents" class ="left realtimeContend_h"> 
</div>
```

---

If you have variable line-heights, you could try removing the css for `.cb` and adding this:

```
if(h != newHeight) {
    $("#left").find(".cb").last().css("height", newHeight-h);
    h = newHeight;         
    $("#left").append("<div class='cb'><input type=\"checkbox\" /></div>");
}
```

---

Here's an update with features you seem to want from the comments:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2MXX/1/)

I added some DOM and this JS:

```
$("#left").on("click", "input", function () {
    var checkedIndexes = "";
    var $cbs = $("#left").find("input");
    $cbs.filter(":checked").each(function () {
        checkedIndexes += "<span>" + $cbs.index(this) + "</span>";
    });
    $("#checkedRows").html(checkedIndexes);
});

$("#checkedRows").on("click", "span", function () {
    var $box = $("#left").find("input").eq(this.innerHTML);
    var $content = $("#content");
    $content.scrollTop(
    $box.offset().top - $content.offset().top + $content.scrollTop());
});
```

If you check boxes, they will show up at the top... if you click on the rows at the top, it will scroll to it.

Comment: As the right side is all a single element, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Actually I want to get all ID of checkbox which is check?

Comment: Here is my update fiddle I want to scroll contend to ckecked element if i click next button http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/TnTj9/7/

Comment: +1 for the original bit of mind reading :)  @smemy I believe the OP wants a `<label for='…'>` and a checkbox with a generated id based on maybe line number?

Comment: Actually I am making like a marker .If i check 2 ,5 ,7 checkbox and click next it scroll to 2 checkbox ,then goes to 5 then 7 if user click previous then goes to 7 ,then 5 or 3

Comment: @Rohit you can do that without the need to know the id. You can go through checked ones by checking its' `.prop('checked')`.

Comment: @omar  can you change some fiddle for better understand

Comment: Rohit - I've updated @smemy 's fiddle a bit do show you one way of putting the ids/labels in place:  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnTj9/8/).  The core of it is still smemy's solution, just refactored a bit.

Comment: @Rohit, Lots of comments since I left for lunch... but I've updated my answer, check the bottom section.

Comment: If user want to scroll to selected checkbox .Mean if i check 2,5 ,10 .and press next it goes to 2 then 5 then 10 or previous button like search functionality http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/f2MXX/2/

Comment: @Rohit, what if the user goes to 2 and then scrolls to 10 and clicks next?

Comment: like that 2,5,10 ,2,5.///. if user at 5 then it press previous it goes to 2 .then user press next it goes again 5..i think difficult question i am trying to do that like search

Comment: @Rohit Perhaps you could make something work based on the stuff I wrote with the `scrollTop()` and such to scroll to an element. If not, should probably ask a new question as this seems to be expanding beyond the original scope.